# iOS:retain memory for a long time in UiButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a button `menuImage`.

and i declare as,By IBOutlet.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *menuImage;
```

on "menuImage button click"

```
- (IBAction)menuButtonClick:(id)sender {
   [sender setHidden:YES];
MenuViewController *viewController = [[MenuViewController alloc]init];
    [self addChildViewController:viewController];
    viewController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
    viewController.view.alpha = 0;
    [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
   // [viewController setHidden:YES];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^
     {
         viewController.view.alpha = 1;
     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

and it will move to other screen. `MenuViewController`

on gave back to intailviewController

in `viewDidLoad`,(in break point)

```
po self.menuImage;
 nil
```

I obtained the `self.menuImage` is nil.

how to retain the process for a long time. please suggest me some answer.

Comment: Are you sure you've connected the button in Interface Builder with your declared menuImage?

Comment: Not that I think this should matter but you are hiding the button when it appears the child VC covers the entire parent VC, so thats strictly not necessary. But, when are you unhiding it?